# Sort by two attributes from the same element in an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

How can I get two attributes from the same element in an xml file, compare them and sort them in numerical order?

The XML elements are:

```
<Parent>
      <Nice to="647429920" from="20200935" />
      <Nice to="647431008" from="20200969" />
      <Nice to="647432224" from="20201007" />
      <Nice to="647437984" from="20201187" />
      <Nice to="647441632" from="20201301" />
      <Nice to="647441760" from="20201305" />
      <Nice to="647443360" from="20201355" />
      <Nice to="647445728" from="20201429" />
      <Nice to="647446144" from="20201442" />
      <Nice to="647447296" from="20201478" />
      <Nice to="647450400" from="20201575" />
      <Nice to="647450752" from="20201586" />
      <Nice to="647451232" from="20201601" />
</Parent>
```

I've tried to do this as a start to get the attributes:

```
foreach (XElement node in xDoc.DocumentElement)
            {
                    Console.Write(node.Element("Nice").Attribute("to").Value);
                    Console.Write(node.Element("Nice").Attribute("from").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(node.Element("Entry").Attribute("from").Value);
            }
```

This breaks with a Cast exception.

Edit:

Updated to this:

```
 var xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
foreach (XElement node in xDoc1.Elements())
{
Console.WriteLine(node.Element("Nice").Attribute("to").Value);
Console.WriteLine(node.Element("Nice").Attribute("from").Value);
}
```

But the code within the body only gets read once and then the program exits. It does not loop through the entire xml file.

Comment: What is `base.Write()`? What "Cast exception" where?

Comment: my bad Console.Write, I think the exception is thrown at XElement as it doesn't reach the body

Comment: What does "at XElement as it doesn't reach the body" mean?

Comment: The code does not execute within the loop. XElement is XElement node. Node seems to be empty it passes the loop and exits.

Comment: `XDocument` doesn't have a `DocumentElement` property. This is actually `XmlDocument`, isn't it? So there's no `XElement` anywhere. Yes, Daniele has it.

Comment: Yep my bad again :(

Comment: You should take care not to add usings for both `System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Xml`. You should also try to explain things clearly and thoroughly in detailed plain English, instead of expecting people to interpret cryptic stuff like "Node seems to be empty it passes the loop and exits." That sentence communicates nothing clear or specific. Help people help you. Don't make them play guessing games.

Comment: yes apologies I work too fast and write to fast without being calm

Comment: Working too fast without being calm is the cause of more programming problems and frustration than all other causes combined. When you run into a snag the fastest way to get through it is to take a deep breath and slow to a crawl. Seems counterintuitive, but I've learned that lesson more than once over the last 25 years. I'm not saying it comes naturally for anybody.

Comment: `<Parent/>` should be `</Parent>`.

Comment: Thanks made that edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Daniele's Answer Works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46733435/209259) but there can be some issues and using linq you can skip foreach loops:

First, your values look like integers so using [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.110).aspx) without parsing it to an integer can cause problems (IE when comparing strings `"10" < "2"`).

Secondly, there is no null checking to see if an attribute exists, which will throw a null reference exception.

```
var xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(/* xml path */);
var nodes = xDoc1.Root.Elements("Nice");

var values = nodes
    .Where(n => n.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name == "to"))
    .Select(n => {
      int result;
      int.TryParse(n.Attributes().First(a => a.Name == "to").Value, out result);
      return result;
    })
    .ToList();

values.AddRange(nodes
    .Where(n => n.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name == "from"))
    .Select(n => {
      int result;
      int.TryParse(n.Attributes().First(a => a.Name == "from").Value, out result);
      return result;
    })
    .ToList());

values = values.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
```

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry about that, some code was *pasted* twice in the SO Editor.

Comment: Still errors: n.Attributes: XElement attribute is a method not given in the correct context. values.AddRange(  << Identifier Expected. Then .Where does not exist in the current context

Comment: Thanks but still shows this error: AddRange( << Identifier Expected. Then .Where does not exist in the current context. This line   .Where(n => n.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name == "from"))

Comment: You probably fixed it yourself, but I added nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to cast the 'Xml.XmlElement' returned from the 'DocumentElement' to a 'Linq.XElement'. 
Probably you need something like this:

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
var orderedList = new List<int>();
xDoc.Load(/* xml path */);
var els = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Nice").Cast<XmlNode>();
foreach (var el in els)
{
   Console.WriteLine(el.Attributes.Item(0).Value);
   Console.WriteLine(el.Attributes.Item(1).Value);
}
```

or this code if you want to use xml.linq 
**Edited after @Ed Plunkett tips**

```
var xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(/* xml path */);
var nodes = xDoc1.Elements("Parent").Elements("Nice");
if(nodes != null && nodes.Any()) 
{
   foreach (XElement node in nodes)
   {
       orderedList.Add(int.Parse(node.Attribute("to").Value));
       orderedList.Add(int.Parse(node.Attribute("from").Value));
   }
}
orderedList.Sort();
foreach (var a in orderedList)
{
   Console.WriteLine(a);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: tried the second one using xml.linq still does not enter the body

Comment: Printing the xDoc to the console gives me the xml

Comment: Taking out the where clause it goes through the first row and then exits giving me the first attributes

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes, i've seen the error and corrected adding some check on null reference.

Comment: Was working before the refactoring now breaks on this line nodes != null && nodes.Any()

Comment: it works, any chance we could see how to put this in a sorted numerical list :/

Comment: I could add .OrderBy(e => e.Attribute("to").Value) at the end of .Elements("Nice") but how can I ensure both attributes are being compared and ordered? before writing to the console

Comment: `nodes != null` is not required.  If no nodes exists, you always get an empty list.

Comment: This doesn't work as the nodes.Attribute gives a string and orderedList is of type int